# Server Firewall Settings

Tags: tcp, port, firewall, portforwarding

Hi I have a server running on my computer, and the client program tries to connect with my IP address on port 5000 through a TCP connection. How do I get my computer to allow this? I know it has something to do with port forwarding settings but I forget how to do it. I use Verizon if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your location / computer / OS which you don't specify. It sounds though like your running a server at home??

To accomplish this in Windows, I would set a rule on my router to allow tcp over 5000 and specify to which local IP address to forward it and on the receiving PC/server in Windows Firewall set a custom rule to again allow tcp 5000.

Comment: Yes I'm running on a DELL PC at home with Windows Vista